# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin is therefore not allowed access

Tags: cors, sapui5, http-get, sap-web-ide, sap-business-bydesign

I am checking whether a particular URL is currently up or not, by adding a HTTP GET functionality to a button in my UI5 application.

For this, the code is as below:

```
        _onButtonPress: function () {
    
         var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
        xhr.open('GET', this.getView().byId("sap_Responsive_Page_0-content-sap_ui_layout_form_SimpleForm-1476966827717-content-sap_m_Input-1476966871600").getValue(), true);
        xhr.send();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = processRequest;
        function processRequest(e) {
if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
    var response = (xhr.responseText);
    alert(response);    }
}},
```

For the URL input, we are using HTTPS requests only.

But when I put a value for the URL and test the button, I get:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://my3XXXXXXX6.sapbydesign.com/sap/byd/runtime/(entered URL). No '**Access-Control-Allow-Origin**' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://application browser url' is therefore not allowed access.

The idea is to check the status of URL and set the status state from the URL status.

[image]

How can I prevent this from happening?

Br
Suraj N

Answer (score 1):

This is browser protection against a class of attacks called [Cross-Site Request Forgeries](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)).

As explained in the error message, you cannot get this to work unless the linked website (in this case https://my3****6.sapbydesign.com/sap/byd/runtime/) adds an appropriate [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) header to its response.

Comment: So, you are suggesting , that this is something which is to be done from the server side?

Comment: @dexter If the sapdesign.com website is under your control, you can add the appropriate header to its response.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is happening because you App (the one that is Starting the get) is hosted in domain A and the service is hosted in domain B. For security reasons, browsers won't let you do that.

One way to fix it is getting the server to allow certain Http verbs from your domains. But if you are not in control of the server side you won't be able To do that.

Another way is to create a proxy server on your end and configure it to relay all the requests to the original server you were intending to issue the get request.

Then on your original app you issue the get to your proxy server.

You can do that directly in eclipse: 
http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw74/helpdata/de/2d/3f5fb63a2f4090942375df80abc39f/content.htm

Or you can start a proxy on node as well:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-connect-proxy

Comment: Thanks you both for your replies..
The server is hosted in SAP cloud and I am using SAP WebIDE available on HCP trial..
Is there any way for the connection...
maybe by importing the ssl certificates into the account?!

Comment: Check [this](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/1.34.7/docs/guide/44062441f3bd4c67a4f665ae362d1109.html) tutorial. It explains how to configure the proxy on SAP WEB IDE. Basically you will create a so called 'destination' in you IDE and this will act as a proxy. Search on the link i mentionaded for "proxy configuration".

Comment: Hi @Geraldo, thats one possibility to do, but we have many tenants..and this would mean adding all those(for example 100 destinations for 100 tenants)..
Will adding the ssl certificates of the BYD tenants to HCP work?

Comment: Hi @dexter. Well, then your best chance is to config the right headers on the server side. It's not a SSL cerficate issue. It won't make a difference. It's a bit of a pain to get the headers configured properly but is definitelly doable. This [link from html5 rocks](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) has a nice tutorial on what you need to do on the server side.

Comment: Hi @Geraldo, I tried adding the tenant info in the destination, but when I check the connectivity.
Failure Reason: 'peer not authenticated'